# How to Multiple User Working in One Workspace at "ECLIPSE"?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I need to Working With My partner At one Workspace At Eclipse 2020. But Eclipse dosen't let us to do this, even two user working in separate time. I found this solution  to remove .loc at "**{WORKSPACE_PATH}/.metadata** " to release the lock of another user. So is there any bether idea for solving this problem?
thx.

Comment: Use version control, e.g. built-in Git.

Comment: Removing the lock file will result in all sorts of errors. You need to use separate workspaces and a source control system like Git to merge changes.